# SSRS Dataset Properties doesn't have expected options

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, rdlc

I'm practicing to make a dynamic columns report following [this guide](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20031.ssrs-how-to-calculate-total-of-dynamic-columns.aspx).

In the article Dataset properties windows looks like
[image]

However, when I tried it myself. Mine was like
[image]

I guess I might miss some setting then I search such as "SSRS DataSet Properties", "SSRS DataSet Properties options", "SSRS DataSet Properties only General option" but couldn't find **How to list all options like the article**.

My Visual Studio is 2013 ultimate and SQL server version is 2014 enterprise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your report is not SSRS (SQL Server Reporting Service)

Make sure you create ssrs project like image below

[image: Create SSRS Report]

Comment: I didn't notice [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165571/difference-between-rdlc-and-ssrs). Seems RDLC didn't have the [element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252109(v=VS.90).aspx) I need. I gotta to find another solution to fit my demand. thx still.